# Replacing NULL data with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm looking to replace small bits of NULL data using scipy without having to link them up with an unrealistic linear line (the data is to visualized). I've had a look at some documentation and examples but struggle to relate what I've seen to a use in my context.

For instance for a period such as this below;

[image]

I have a method to find the last value before and the first value after this set of NULL entries.

How would I use these values and return an object of three interpolated values to write into my dataset?

EDIT:

I am trying to create two numpy arrays from data which has two real values enclosing a series of NULL values. I get the data as a list from a SQL server class I have written. I am trying to do it like this;

```
    time = connection.getColumnData('DateTimeStamp', table, extreme_values['start_time'] + '.000', extreme_values['end_time'] + '.000')
    val = connection.getColumnData(column, table, extreme_values['start_time'] + '.000', extreme_values['end_time'] + '.000')
    time = [str(d) for d in time]
    #val = [float(d) for d in val]

    val_num = np.asarray(val, dtype=float)
    time_num = np.asarray(time, dtype='datetime64')
    not_nan = ~np.isnan(val_num, dtype=bool)
```

But it breaks at runtime on the line;

```
    filled_data = np.interp(time_num, time_num[not_nan], val_num[not_nan])
```

Held in each val_num;

```
array([ 5.625 ,     nan,     nan,     nan,  5.4375])
```

In time_num;

```
array(['2012-04-05T07:30:00+0000', '2012-04-05T08:00:00+0000',
   '2012-04-05T08:30:00+0000', '2012-04-05T09:00:00+0000',
   '2012-04-05T09:30:00+0000'], dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

In not_non;

```
 array([ True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Please provide a short example of cut&paste-able data and a few lines of code to demonstrate the intended plot (that contains the linear straight lines you want to get rid of).

Comment: well the point is there is no code i'm afraid. i looked into reshaping a linear array but am unsure if this is too cumbersome and I'm not taking advantage of scipy as I could be

Comment: i'm not looking for a worked solutions just a point in the right direction with some code extracts

Comment: It is totally unclear, what you are asking for. We don't know what software you use, where the data comes from, how it is processed by you, or you want to be processed and what the result should be.

Comment: some more code now in the answer. what else would you like to know? can you not deduce it's python from the fact it's a python library?

Comment: "it breaks" - how? Please post the full traceback. What is `val_num.dtype`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your data in two numpy arrays (call them `data` and `timestamp`) and you want to fill in `NaN` values in your `data` array based on their timestamp, you could use [`numpy.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
not_nan = ~numpy.isnan(data)
filled_data = numpy.interp(timestamp, timestamp[not_nan], data[not_nan])
```

**EDIT:** Getting your data into numpy arrays is actually the tricky part here. I'm guessing that the result of your `getColumnData` calls is mostly numeric, with a few `None` values where the `NULL`s were. Let's see what happens in that case:

```
In [3]: np.array([4,3,None,4,2,1])
Out[3]: array([4, 3, None, 4, 2, 1], dtype=object)

In [4]: np.isnan(_)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4328b1685393> in <module>()
----> 1 np.isnan(_)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The presence of the `None` means that numpy doesn't know this is a numeric array, which is why the `numpy.isnan` call fails. We can fix that by telling numpy we actually want a numeric array:

```
In [7]: np.array([4,3,None,4,2,1], dtype=float)
Out[7]: array([  4.,   3.,  nan,   4.,   2.,   1.])

In [8]: np.isnan(_)
Out[8]: array([False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. i had no numpy arrays but will have a look down this route. i'm having a bit of trouble creating the arrrays from a list. my code is now in the queston.

Comment: thanks, so that solved the breaking  @ not_nan = ~numpy.isnan(data) the last line seems to be the issue now!

Comment: You need to make your time_num array numeric as well. Just change the dtype='datetime64' to dtype=float.

Comment: ok, i converted the times to epoch. the output array is array([ nan,  nan,  nan]), how's this?

Comment: Not sure, using your example from the question works on my end: np.interp(time_num, time_num[not_nan], val_num[not_nan]) -> array([ 5.625   ,  5.578125,  5.53125 ,  5.484375,  5.4375  ])